# Abstracting from types, & building Entity Framework query dynamically in ASP.NET / C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, blazor

I'm building a self-service reporting tool in Blazor, that allows a user to select a particular dataset (all of which are stored using Entity Framework), then filter by various properties/columns in the database.

Is there a way to abstract from coding in "types" on the web server (like using `IQueryable` or something of the sort) to build a LINQ command dynamically based on user selections?

For example, say we have the following two classes:

```
public class Car
{
    public int Year { get; set; }
    public string Color { get; set; }
    public Company Make { get; set; }
    public string Model { get; set; }
    public int Weight { get; set; }
    public int MilesPerGallon { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

and

```
public class Company
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Country CountryOfOrigin { get; set; }
    public DateTime Founded { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

A user in a user interface would be able to selct "Car" as the database, then select "Where" clauses by restricting properties to various values, and then choose to "slice" on a different property.

An example might be:

Population: Cars, Where:

- Year is between 1970 and 1979.
- The Car's Make (Company) CountryOfOrigin is 'United States'

  - Slice By: Make
  - Sort By: Count, Descending
  - Color By: Miles Per Gallon

How would I write this in such a way that I can abstract the code that builds the SQL query from individual tables / properties etc..

Additionally what would be the "best" way to create metadata on the tables themselves to exclude a table or column (Id) etc. from the front end tool, create my own attributes and dynamically exclude those from the client?

[image]

Comment: Questions that ask "where do I start?" are typically too broad and are not a good fit for this site. People have their own method for approaching the problem and because of this there cannot be a _correct_ answer. Give a good read over [Where to Start](//softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6367) and [edit] your post.

Comment: Thanks--I updated this to have a clear primary question--1.) How to dynamically build the query string dynamically across different datamodels in response to what the user chooses, and a lesser question 2.) How to exclude specific properties from this front-end that ostensibly looks at the database to generate the columns to filter on.

Comment: Maybe you can consider something like OData, I build some OData like requests using [Community.OData.Linq.Json](https://github.com/IharYakimush/comminity-data-odata-linq), you have a sample [here](https://github.com/aguacongas/TheIdServer/tree/master/src/IdentityServer/Aguacongas.IdentityServer.Admin)

Comment: You might want to look at an example I wrote a while ago: https://github.com/conficient/BlazorDynamicList - this was where a list of products have different attributes, so I created a way to render a component which is specific to each product. In your example, each database might have a `<SelectFilters>` component which lists the specific filters for that data. You'd just need some sort of commonality in the app for each database, e.g. implement an `IFilterableDatabase` interface